# Is it true that all cameras of all generations of iPhone can have photo + video geotagging?

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I am a little bit confused about the geotagging feature in iPhone, so I will list all these lines & tell me if any of them is wrong.

1. iPhone 2G has a Rear Camera that can take photo only with photo geotagging.
2. iPhone 3G has a Rear Camera that can take photo only with photo geotagging.
3. iPhone 3Gs has a Rear Camera that can take photo with photo geotagging + record video with video geotagging
4. iPhone 4 has an iSight rear camera that can take photo with photo geotagging + record video with video geotagging, and has FaceTime front camera can take photo with photo geotagging + record video with video geotagging
5. iPhone 4s is the same as iPhone 4 (i.e. it has 2 cameras & each camera can take photo with photo geotagging & record video with video geotagging.
6. iPhone 5 is the same as iPhone 4
7. iPhone 5c is the same as iPhone 4
8. iPhone 5s is the same as iPhone 4

Are any statements from 1 to 8 wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statements are all true.

Though the geotagging on the first iPhone wasn't really precise since there was no built-in GPS : it used the GSM triangulation to localize the phone ([source](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2008/05/geotaggingphoto.html#more)).

Comment: thaxu very musch so wikipedia is wrong then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_2G

Comment: I corrected my answer.

Comment: can u quote the source saying that iPhone 2G uses GSM triangulation

Comment: check my edit !